# ODI 12 how to store a value in a variable or procedure option

Tags: oracle-data-integrator

At the procedure step in the ODI script, I use Jython, take the values ​​​​from the tables I need - I get a string -> put it in VERSION -> I need to pass the VERSION value from the Version_working_0_0 step to test_verion_0_0.

Need to assign values ​​to variables and pass between script steps to build complex logic

[image: Procedure tasks]

Did not find clear information on the topic.
Tried (I get an error):

```
<@ Test = "testvalue"> 
odiRef.setOption("Test", VERSION)
```

Comment: please don't post images of code or error messages

Comment: If you get an error it's always good to post it.
There is no setOptions method in the ODI Substitution API. https://docs.oracle.com/en/middleware/fusion-middleware/data-integrator/12.2.1.4/odikd/substitution-api-reference.html. What is the end result you want? I don't think you need to set it in an option. The Test variable you set in Version_working_0_0 task is accessible in the test_version_0_0 task as well, they share the same scope.

Comment: wow you were right
you can call variables at any step of the procedure)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Test variable you set in Version_working_0_0 task is accessible in the test_version_0_0 task as well, they share the same scope.